# Extract a word from a line, doing this to a specific number of lines

Tags: sed

I want to extract a word from a line, doing this to a specific number of lines.

I have something like this.

```
1. Bill 
2. Joe 1
3. Sue 1
```

I want to extract separately the words Bill, Joe and Sue. I am trying to use the `sed` command but I have had no success.

Comment: you might need to provide more information... I guess you want to do that on a file containing a large number of entries. To answer correctly, you need to let us know how your file is organised... I mean if the names are always in the second, fourth and fifth column, then unsing awk is easy

Comment: thanks for the update, try `awk '{print $2}' filename`

Comment: Is that always the second word on the line? Or any word that is an acceptable 3 or 4 letter word that is all [a-z] starting with a capital. Or are you just looking for exactly those three words?

Comment: Whats the logic behind what to extract?

Comment: The second word, there are 2 or 3 words . The first is a number followed by . , the second is a name , and the third is also a number but sometimes it may miss.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I will use the cut command cause it is showing the names on different lines.

Comment: If you have found an answer that helps you, please use the tick mark alongside it to show you've accepted that answer.

Comment: @MadalinNeacsu : the `awk` command also prints the names on different lines... and in general it is more flexible than `cut`, you can do many more things with `awk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `cut` to extract the second field delimited by space:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt          
1. Bill 
2. Joe 1
3. Sue 1

$ cut -d' ' -f2 file.txt
Bill
Joe
Sue
```

Comment: If i have the file named employees:
1. Fred
2. Billy 1
3. Sally 1
4. Jim 2
5. Jane 3
and i have another file named managers :
1. Fred
2. Billy
3. Sally

I want to print each employee with his manager.
For exemple : 
Fred
Billy Fred
Sally Fred
Jim Billy
Jane Sally

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner of this site and i do not know how to write in a comment to display the table.

Comment: @MadalinNeacsu hmmm..thats a totally different question..please ask it as a new question..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for this. Just select and print the second field.

```
awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have just these 3 lines a `sed 's/[0-9. ]//g' filename`
do the job.

Select a line with `sed -e '2!d' -e 's/[0-9. ]//g' filename` this just give you `Joe` as output.